# Can Langton's Ant draw a Penrose tiling?

Tags: geometry, tiling

Given the possibility for automata like [Langton's Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant) to lead to complex, intricate structures, I'm curious whether a Penrose tiling can be generated via this sort of local exploration. More formally:

> Suppose we have an "ant" which can take steps of $e^{k\cdot\pi i/5}$ for any $0\le k <10$, leaving an edge behind it. Does there exist an algorithm for the ant which takes as input only the edges it has drawn within some radius $R$ and outputs a direction to take the next step in, such that the ant draws all and only those edges present in some Penrose tiling?

We might give the ant some more flexibility by permitting it a finite number of internal states to adjust as it moves around, turning it into a sort of 2D Turing machine.

It seems plausible that an argument from the aperiodicity of the Penrose tilings could show this impossible, but it's not clear to me quite how this would go through.

Comment: I doubt it, because we know that tile placement depends on arbitrarily large neighborhoods of existing tiles, so any such algorithm would need to consider the configuration of edges beyond any finite radius $R$.

Comment: Must the ant draw every edge correctly the first time, or is it allowed to erase previously drawn edges (as Langton's ant does)? If allowed to erase edges, we could ask that for every possible edge, we will reach the correct final state after finitely many flips - or, more strongly, ask that there is a maximum number of times any edge is flipped.

Comment: @heropup I'm aware of this fact, but it doesn't obviously rule things out to me, because the ant can use the position of the boundary it's currently tracing (e.g. do something special when it crosses a corner of the polygon it's extending outwards). I agree that if the tiling were *already* drawn, it wouldn't be able to reliably predict its surroundings beyond radius $R$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: I was imagining no erasure, but would be interested in the erasure case as well! (If the ant can erase and rescale itself, it can certainly draw iterative inflations of the Penrose tiling, which gives arbitrarily many ever-smaller tiles but doesn't cover the whole plane.)

Comment: I doubt this is possible. One generally needs to know the hierarchical information in order to complete a Penrose tiling to infinity - the local matching rules will often lead to 'dead ends' unless you use the fact that you know where you are in a supertile. So, my guess is that your ant would need to base the algorithm on local information on an ever-greater radius, in which case it's not really local (at least not uniformly).